# Conversion failed converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, casting, uniqueidentifier

I have a set of about 200 unique ID's from a revenue batch that I need to run a stored procedure against. My idea was to create a temp table, insert the unique values, run the stored proc against the temp table and drop the temp table. However whenever I execute my code I am receiving the error message "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier." I can not figure out why I am getting this error. Is anyone familiar with this error that could possibly help me out? Can you look at my code and see the reason for this message? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code Below with sample size unique ID's:

```
CREATE TABLE #Removal (RevID uniqueidentifier, LUID char (12))
INSERT  INTO #Removal(RevID, LUID)VALUES
(Cast ('rev-55326898'AS uniqueidentifier), '8-11838757'),(Cast ('rev-55326899'AS uniqueidentifier), '8-16960881')
declare @field1 uniqueidentifier
declare @field2 INT
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select RevID from #Removal
Open cur
fetch next from cur into @field1
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
exec USP_REVENUE_DELETE @field1, @field2
fetch next from cur into @field1
End
Close cur
deallocate cur
Drop table #Removal
```

Comment: rev-55326898 is (clearly) not a GUID

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187942.aspx should help

Answer (score 1):

Your values (ie: rev-55326898) don't match the format for a unique identifier in SQL Server.

A unique identifier in SQL Server is a 16-byte GUID. There are 2 ways to initialize a value for the data type (from MSDN):

> - By using the NEWID function.
> - By converting from a string constant in the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, in which each x is a hexadecimal
>     digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example,
>     6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier
>     value.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: "...don't match the format for a unique identifier in SQL Server." - or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueidentifier from string needs the xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx form.